# React-native white screen

Tags: android, react-native

Why does the application in react-native takes sometime in opening.
White screen appears before the main activity appears. If I create a native activity before the react-native-activity loads it doesn't shows white screen before load of the native activity.

Answer (score 3):

Because starting react native takes a lot of work, especially starting up the javascript interpreter, then all the polyfills and other framework pieces that need to be initialized.  If you want fast, write actual native.  Or find ways to hide it, such as initializing the system in the background while a splash screen is showing.

That's actually one of the reasons air bnb is no longer using react native.  See https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/sunsetting-react-native-1868ba28e30a for an interesting article on some of the drawbacks they found.